# Prove that there is a solution that depends smoothly on the coefficients

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, implicit-function-theorem

Consider the equation $x^4+a_0x^3+a_1x^2+2a_2x+a_3=0$. Prove that there is $\delta > 0$ such that if $|a_i-1| < \delta$ for $i=0,1,2,3$, then the above equation has a solution that depends smoothly on the $a_i$'s.

I assume this is an exercise on the Implicit function theorem, but I don't know how to apply it in this case. I thought about the function $\mathbb R^4\to \mathbb R, (a_0,a_1,a_2,a_3)\mapsto  x^4+a_0x^3+a_1x^2+2a_2x+a_3$, but the theorem requires that the function vanishes at some point, whereas this function contains a formal variable and cannot vanish.

Comment: Note: If all $a_i$ are equal to $1$, then $x=-1$ is a root.

Comment: The map you want is probably from the coefficients to the four roots, not to the polynomial.  In any case the crux of the problem lies in showing that there are no repeated roots when all $a_i$ are approximately equal to one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function you have defined is not a map to $\mathbb{R}$. It is a map to $\mathbb{R}[x]$. Almost certainly you want a map $\mathbb{R}^5 \to \mathbb{R}$ which is defined by $(a_0, a_1, a_2, a_3, x) \mapsto x^4 + a_0x^3 + a_1x^2 + 2a_2x + a_3 $. In this case, if you think of this as a function $\mathbb{R}^{4+1} \to \mathbb{R}^1$, you'll find the implicit function theorem to be a little more friendly. In particular, if you take for example all the $a_i = 1$, you can find a solution given by $x = -1$. Now you just need to show that $x$ can be eliminated in terms of the $a_i$ by using the implicit function theorem, i.e. checking that the $x$ derivative of this function of $5$ variables has a non-zero derivative at the point in question (as it is clearly more than just $C^1$, it is $C^\infty$ as a polynomial in these variables).

Comment: Thanks! What point do you mean? I believe I can take $p=(1,1,1,1,-1)$. In this case, writing the function you defined as $F$, we have $F(p)=0$ and $F_x(p)\ne 0$. Then by the Implicit function theorem, there is $\delta > 0$ and a smooth $\phi: V=(1-\delta,1+\delta)^4\to \mathbb R$ with $\phi(1,1,1,1)=-1$ and $F(a_0,a_1,a_2,a_3,\phi(a_0,a_1,a_2,a_3))=0$ for all $(a_0,a_1,a_2,a_3)\in V$. So $\phi(a_0,a_1,a_2,a_3)$ is the local solution we need.

Comment: Yes, that point. This is pretty much exactly what I had in mind.